# Is it possible in SQL to use a FieldByName function when using an alias field

Tags: sql, ms-access, delphi

I am using a MS Access database in Delphi. I want to extract the difference between two date field,Date In and Date Out; in the table, tblGuestInfo. I want to save the difference between these two dates as an integer variable, inights.

I have the following code.

```
with datamod.qryguestinfo do 
begin
 close;
 sql.clear
 sql.add('SELECT DATEDIFF ("d","[Date In]","[Date Out]") As DateDifference')
 sql.add('From tblGuestInfo');
 open;
 inights := fieldbyname['DateDifference'].asInteger;
 open;
end;
```

When I run it, the following error message appears "qryguestinfo field: 'DateDiff' not found".
I assume the error message comes from `inights := fieldbyname['DateDiff'].asInteger` code.

I am still farely new at SQL and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to open the query.

Comment: Don't use reserved words as names. DateDiff is a reserved word - intrinsic function. If you insist on using then enclose in [ ] characters: `AS [DateDiff]` but spare yourself the aggravation and just don't do it.

Comment: I shall change it, thank you for the advice.

Comment: Could you please get into the habit of including relevant info in your q, in this case the datatype of your qryguestinfo table.  Btw, the 'DateDiff' fiekd will not actually exist until to you open the table unless you create persistent fields on tthe table in the IDE.

Comment: @MartynA, I did not know my qryguestinfo table could have a datatype or are you referring to the field datatypes in the table?

Comment: @CameronVanRooyen: `datamod.qryguestinfo` certainly has a type. Maybe `TFDQuery`. Anyhow, try putting the `Open` *before* the `FieldByName` line. (Because the time machine hasn't yet been invented.)

Comment: The qryguestinfo table itself,  Just look at its declaration on your datamod datamodule.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand:  Or create persistent FIelds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the other answer is incorrect in stating that the DateDiff can only be used within Access.

The following works fine in Delphi using the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 provider:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select id, DateDiff(''d'', Field1, Field2) as DiffInDays from table1';
  AdoQuery1.Open;
end;
```

So there is no need to do anything in Access to get the result you want.

Btw, the answer to your q is a qualified "yes".  If you are not using persistent TFields (fields created in the IDE by right-clicking the dataset and selecting 'Fields Editor') then the fields aren't actually created until the table is opened, after which you can use FieldByName *until* the dataset is closed.  If you create persistent TFields, then the fields exist all the time, but still can only be used to get (or set) field values while the dataset is open.  Easiest way to create persistent fields is to set the query's SQL.Text in the IDE and then use 'Add all fields' from the FieldEditor's context menu.